# How do you to create a JFrame with simple text?

Tags: java, swing, text, jframe, jpanel

I just want to make a JFrame that will say "Hello world", nothing big, no interaction needed. How do I do this?

I can create the JFrame, however I do not know how to put a JPanel with simple text in it.

Here is what I got so far

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Relief Valve");
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLocation(500,300);
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Take a look at the swing [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html). It even has a hello world example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating the `JPanel`, try:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("this is my text");
frame.add(label);
frame.pack();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("Hello World App"); 
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
window.add(new JLabel("Hello World"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

I'm currently on a mobile device but I'll be happy to document that when I get on a computer, feel free to ask any questions though.

Comment: I added the BorderLayout() and the BorderLayout.CENTER to my frame/window, it doesn't seem like it changed anything though. Exactly what is it supposed to do?

Comment: A `BorderLayout` divides the window into 5 different regions; north east south west and center. If you use BorderLayout.NORTH you can observe how it will stay at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `JLabel` (witch is from `Swing` library) the code for that is:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello world");
```

if u want to set it to a specific loaction you need to create a render method :

```
public void render(Graphics g){
    g.drawString(label,x,y);
}
```

the `x` and `y` is the position of the string with your `label`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a JFrame with a simple text, you have to create a *label* and attach it to your frame.

Let's assume you have a `JFrame` created:

`JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("My Frame");`

Let's create the text label:

`JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Text");`

To change a text of already created label:

`myLabel.setText("New Text");`

And eventually to clear the label:

`myLabel.setText("");`

Let's connect all the dots:

```
myFrame.add(myLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
myFrame.pack();
```

To learn more about JFrames, check: https://javatutorial.net/swing-jframe-basics-create-jframe